# What's the worst programming book you've ever read?

Tags: books

What's the worst programming-related or technical book you've ever read? This can be any book which one way or another can be connected to programming, as long as it's not fiction.

Comment: I was browsing my library, but I wasn't able to find it... Probably because I throwed it into the trash... I can't even remember the title, but that was about COM+

Comment: Fictional as in the book doesn't exist? Or fictional as in a fiction book?

Comment: @Joe D: Sorry, I meant 'fiction book'. I'll change the question accordingly.

Comment: and where is the reopen btn?

Answer (score 31):

Any book that allows you to teach yourself X in Y hours.

I've read some in the past but once read you don't know any details whatsoever about X and you can't use the book as a reference for X either. After discovering that it seems better to go for the big books.

Comment: THIS. The only SAMS book I bought that "teaches me" VB.NET in 21 days was so ridiculously out of sync with reality that I literally threw it away.

Comment: I may get shouted down on this but I think as a corollary, the "C for Dummies" books were actually pretty good for what they were trying to do. The guy who wrote them invented the "for Dummies" concept (and sold it), so he was a pretty adept technical writer. They might not hold up so well now if I go re-read them but they did stand out to me at the time as a good exception to the "___ for Dummies"/"___ in ___ hours/days" being crap rule.

Comment: To me, the "for Dummies" books are great for what they are -- a compact (if less detailed) explanation of a complex concept, geared toward people that don't already know much about it.  They'd probably suck as the only reference, but they go a long way toward helping someone who's new to the concept wrap their minds around it, without oversimplifying to the point of being wrong.  That's more than i can say for a *lot* of other books.

Comment: I think the biggest problem with some of these books is the title.  If you change it to "A Brief Introduction to X" you'd have a better picture of what you're getting.  I agree they aren't good for the details or as a reference you'll keep coming back to, but that's not really what they're intended for.

Comment: Perhaps they are referring to "Venus-days" - they are much longer than Earth-days.

Comment: If this is the series I'm thinking of then they're also printed on something like toilet paper. Kind-of ironic really.

Answer (score 26):

Hardcore Java

[image: alt Hardcore Java]

This book was written by a person that
 truly did not understand the finer
 points of java. He didn't even
 understand by ref or by val parameter
 passing. I'll quote the top rated
 amazon review: (it's a 1 star)

> In the preface, the author states that
>   the goal of this book is to transform
>   a developer from the intermediate
>   level to a true guru. In the back
>   cover it even promises that "you'll
>   master the art of writing error-prone
>   (sic!) code", and the reference to
>   "error-prone code" sadly finds its
>   confirmation once one starts reading.
>
> It takes about two chapters to
>   demolish the author's credibility as a
>   guru, and you will be reading the rest
>   of the book with a skeptical eye,
>   doubting every assertion that looks
>   questionable and suspecting that the
>   author is talking well above his level
>   of competence, and patronizing about
>   it too!
>
> The first chapters are an atrocious
>   review of some Java concepts, densely
>   packed with serious mistakes, not
>   typos, mistakes (plenty of typos too).
>
> As an example, on page 9 the
>   definition of the `for' statement is
>   wrong, a simple check of the Java
>   Language Specification would have
>   spared the author some embarrassment.
>
> On page 15 the author gives us wrong
>   rules for labels in Java, and in the
>   same page he confuses the logic of the
>   'break' and 'continue' statements,
>   providing also a logically wrong code
>   example, just to screw-up things even
>   better.
>
> I would not know how to describe the
>   section on "Chained deferred
>   initialization" on page 53, "raving"
>   maybe. This one is cited in the errata
>   page at oreilly.com, and the "author
>   regrets that it slipped through the
>   proverbial cracks". I am more
>   concerned that something like that has
>   been actually written (complete with
>   code samples!), than that it has
>   passed unscathed through editing and
>   reviewing. Let's hope it was written
>   by somebody else playing with the
>   author's laptop. Somebody who does not
>   know what JVM means.
>
> There are also less severe but equally
>   confidence-abating points, like, on
>   page 25, the form:
>
> new String("A button to show" + text);
>
> which we should not find in books for
>   guru wannabes.
>
> The author is probably a productive
>   software architect, some points, later
>   in the book, are interesting, though
>   nothing could be defined advanced, but
>   he does not know Java better than an
>   average developer, and this book does
>   not add very much to an intermediate
>   level, apart, maybe, from a warning
>   about writing books: writing a book
>   can transform you from a good
>   developer into a bad author.
>
> It is sad that we are flooded with
>   such mediocre and unprofessional
>   "error-prone"publications from such
>   once reputable publishers, from time
>   to time I still re-read and enjoy the
>   conciseness, clarity and value of
>   classics like K&R's "The C Programming
>   Language" and I wonder why today's
>   output is so vastly inferior.
>
> As one of the few exceptions, I
>   strongly recommend Bloch's "Effective
>   Java" (Addison-Wesley) which is truly
>   a book written by a guru. After
>   reading that one, "Hardcore Java" will
>   seem even emptier.

Its [errata](http://oreilly.com/catalog/hardcorejv/errata/hardcorejv.confirmed) on O'Reilly is (last time I checked) 20+ pages long.

edit: just checked it, default settings in word, it's 23 pages long.

Comment: I have an O'Reilly rant building up. I wonder where it is going to blow. It needs more data, first.

Comment: If you notice, the current page for the book says there's no errata for the book. You have to dig it out.

Comment: **Are you serious?!** And that is not a newer edition?

Comment: (I haven't seen the book.) To summarize the reviews at Amazon, I'd suggest a book title of "From C to Java: How to apply your hard-earned credentials to a new language and become an instant expurt(sic)"

Comment: O'Reilly books are very poorly edited... I am not impressed with them as a publishing company.

Comment: Many O'Reilly books -- perhaps most -- are excellent. But not all are...

Comment: "errata" indeed: "(xvi) Replace  Paragraph
I would like to take a moment to say �Hi� to my brother Paul and my sister Debbie. I 
currently live in Germany, and although I am very happy living here, I miss my brother 
and sister greatly.

with 
I would also like to thank my new wife Alma for being the wonderful person she is and 
supporting me through all of my efforts to write and maintain this book."

Answer (score 14):

I still remember how bad this book was:

[image: Oracle9i: A Beginner's Guide]

[Oracle9i: A Beginner's Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0072192798)

I was angry reading through it.  I'll quote from my Amazon review:

> Almost immediately, I was disappointed: Chapter 1 is a tribute to how amazing Oracle is and how godlike Larry Ellison is and it's filled with pages and pages of revenues and sales. What a waste of paper. Then Chapter 2 tells me how to use newsgroups and Google: more wasted paper. I come to Chapter 3 and I think I finally get into learning something. Then I notice they concentrate on Sun Solaris as the operating system which isn't very helpful to a person trying to learn this on his own at home.
>
> Then on page 84 I read, "In earlier releases of the Beginner's Guide, we walked you through the Oracle server installation. With Oracle 8i and now 9i, it's too big a topic to cover in a book this size." That's how they start out their step-by-step walkthrough of setting up your first Oracle database. Oh, the last step reads, "12. Read the rest of this book." To me, the book wasted 80 pages then tells me installation would take too long. Very disappointing.

Comment: sounds like a waste of paper!

Comment: You don't run Solaris at home?  I did during that window of time when it was free...

Comment: Wow. Sounds like an amazing book.

Answer (score 13):

1. **Let Us C** -  Yashavant P. Kanetkar
2. **Object Oriented Programmig with C++** - E Balagurusamy

Comment: +1 for the swcond one. This book is not known outside India at all, but is quite famous in universities in south india. Perhsps the fact that the author was the vice chancellor of a university helped this _fame_. The contents are more like it was written by someone who just completed a semester in C++.

Comment: @Nivas : Yeah ! Both Bala and Kanetkar's books are crap still most of the students in Indian universities are referring that book.

Comment: I would upvote this more times if I could. Both Bala and Kanetkar have destroyed many many young minds.

Comment: @Anna I C. (C++ to be specific.)

Comment: I wish I could give you +100 for this, I see people who swear by these book all the time and then reading the code they write makes cry.

Answer (score 13):

[image]

**Worst. Book. Ever.**

It's the size of a phone book, and it's laid out like a sort of recipe book. It's basically a massive collection of thousands of code snippets for accomplishing various tasks, taken completely out of context and often wrong or broken or dated.

The only thing more hilarious is their follow-up book, [Jamsa's C/C++/C# Programmers Bible](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0766846822). Because those languages are *totally* interchangeable, right?

**Would you buy a book on programming from [this man](http://jamsamediagroup.com/)?**

Comment: +1 for C/C++/C#. Actually, I'd like to do a +1 for C/C++ as well.

Comment: +1 for mentioning C++/C# interchaneability... I use C++ codez in my C# all the time.

Comment: What's next... C/C++/C#/Java? Or Perl/Python/C++/Ruby/Java/VHDL/Prolog?

Comment: I used that book in college.  Or, at least I bought it, it was was too big to carry around.

Comment: Looks like the author [setup his own publishing company](http://jamsamediagroup.com/bio.htm), published his book, and then distributed it to 70 countries in 28 languages.

Comment: He 'taught' Web Development, but his homepage is created with.. MS Word. He is also 'proficient'  in like 15 programming languages..

Answer (score 11):

The worst book I ever read was **Ingegneria del codice** by McConnell Steve.

[image]

Yes, it is the Italian translation of the best book I ever read: Code Complete. But the translation was so bad that I had to buy the original version. It has been the last translated technical book I bought. Since then, I only read technical books in English.

Comment: +1, translations (in any languages) ar almost always bad.

Comment: +1 Oh yes translations. French is my native language, and I had to buy original books a couple of time. Now I buy the original version and no more translations.

Comment: I think it's true to all language translations. Of course it's possible one specific book or another to have got a good translation.

Comment: @MAK: Agreed. I try to avoid translations whenever I can and always go for the original. However, when the original is in a language I don't speak, then I don't have much choice.

Comment: @gablin: This brings up an interesting point. In all my life as a programmer I've always seen the best programming/CS books being in English. Apart from very very beginner level books (which have good English equivalents anyway) I haven't heard the praises of any in any language. Are there any worth reading that's not that I'm not aware of?

Comment: @MAK: Not sure I understand what you're asking. What do you mean by "of any in any language"?

Comment: @gablin: I'm pretty sure he means "Are there any programming books worth reading in any language *other than English*?"

Comment: @gablin: I mean that fragment to be read as "of any (books) in any language (other than English)" :).

Comment: @Tim Goodman, @MAK: Ah, that's how I suspected it was to be phrased, but I had to ask to make sure. (It's all in the details.). ^^ Well, I don't have an answer for that.

Comment: *@MAK @Pierre303 @Bigown @gablin* That is the same sweeping generalization you yourselves hate about programmers or a given niche. If, say, most sites done in PHP are the of work of poor programmers---and the number of unskilled people churning out business code in CB---do those facts reflect the quality of the language or what a skilled programmer can do? Certainly not.

Comment: *@MAK @Pierre303 @Bigown @gablin* Those two items are the result of economics, time constraints, and human nature. Please don't let the rarity of well-translated programming or technical books deceive you. Furthermore, I think few books are written in other languages about programming (or computers) by highly qualified individuals because English is the *lingua franca* of the computer world, commercially and academically; so qualified individuals are likely to gravitate toward English in the first place. Major exceptions would be large target populations, such as Hindi, Chinese, or Spanish.

Comment: *@MAK @Pierre303 @Bigown @gablin* I have completed a significant portion of my first major translation, and I take a certain amount of pride, if you will, in the quality of my work. In fact, sometimes I find the need to improve upon the author's writing by breaking up run-on sentences and removing excess wording, for example. Quality translations take, first of all, a client who can accurately judge a translator's work; and second, enough time or money (choose two, remember). *(continued below)*

Comment: *@MAK @Pierre303 @Bigown @gablin* These are the same two problems in software, as well. Technical books, especially programming language books, have great time pressure because of evolving standards---usually the translation has to be done before the technology is updated, which would make the book obsolete. *(out of space for links, see below)*

Comment: *@MAK @Pierre303 @Bigown @gablin* I knew I had read [an article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/do-not-buy-this-book.html) by Jeff about this. It only took two searches to [find it](http://www.google.com/search?q=publishing+programming+book+hard+work+outdated). Never mind, it was actually the second hit in my [first search](http://www.google.com/search?q=coding+horror+programming+books+outdated), but I didn't recognize it without the right keywords.

Comment: *@MAK @Pierre303 @Bigown @gablin* **TLDR Version:** The statements above need to be qualified. To say "translations are almost always bad" is like saying "software is almost always bad". It is unhelpful at best, and untrue at worst, without being more specific. *(Since this is so long already, I will have to find another place for my **O'Reilly rant**.)*

Comment: @Mark C: are you on extacy or something like that ;) ;) ? 6 big comments in 30 minutes. Why not asking a question instead ?

Comment: *@Pierre303* I did not think of asking a question, because this was a reply to comments above. Do you think I should post a question? If so, how should I phrase it?

Comment: Yes I think it would be interesting to ask a question about that particular subject.

Comment: *@Pierre303* Then what should I ask? (And why should I ask about translation on a programmers' site?)

Comment: @Mark C, easy now.  The basic problem is that a translator needs to be very well technically founded to be able to understand what to translate, and orally well founded to be able to express it fluently in another language.  I believe editors have simply underestimated this.

Answer (score 10):

This book was our reading list for a module on C++ in college.

It seemed to be a kinda of 2 for 1 purchase so we wouldn't have to buy a UML book.

The book's huge size combined with no flow and an obsession with ants is why it get my vote.

[image]

I think it may be in the running for the worst cover on a computer book.

Comment: Kinda messed up how a book about programming loves its bugs so...

Comment: @cHao: Well, it *is* a C++ book...

Comment: I had to read this one for my uni course too... it's pretty dry, and hard to follow in places, but it's been written deliberately so that you have to have a tutor to guide you through it!

Comment: I actually tried to read 5th edition. It's horrible. Sure, it's a big nice book but it's just sooo verbose. I've read a book which covered maybe 70% of this book's contents in just 300 B5 pages.

Comment: Its worst sin is using concepts before they are introduced. Thats the reason I went with Robert Lafore.

Comment: Fighting the urg to lol so hard right now.

Comment: I enjoy Deitel books. I have the Java and C Deitel books. They are ordered in a similar fashion. The repetition makes it easier for me to learn.

Comment: That's the one that my high school used to use, back when we programmed in C++ and not Java.

Comment: That's the most amazing cover I've ever seen!

Comment: And the emphasis on Web programming? WTF? Who the heck uses C++ for that?

Comment: I learnt java with a Deitel book, thought it was great.

Comment: I love how they throw in everything that's trendy on the cover
C++!
Web Programming!
Object Oriented Design!
UML!

Answer (score 9):

[image: Pro PHP Security]

[Pro PHP Security](http://books.google.com/books?id=lVXnmsCCd3wC) by Snyder & Southwell for Apress.

Whilst I've met a lot of webdev books and tutorials with an extremely poor attitude to security (hence [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2119083/18936) cry for help), this book reaches new depths by having code packed full of security holes *in a book that is supposed to be all about security*.

I never read it in full, with loads of chapters barely touching on PHP, but even a cursory flick through revealed HTML-injections (XSS) in almost every example, even in the chapter about how to avoid XSS attacks. There's SQL-injection. There's directory traversal. This is in the ‘how to do it’ examples, not the ‘here's a common mistake to avoid’ bit! There are even (inadequate) suggestions on how to ‘safely’ use `eval` and `system`, which could much more sensibly be replaced by the word ‘DON'T’.

What solutions it does offer are largely wrong-headed and discredited approaches based on ‘sanitising’ or randomly escaping at the input stage, instead of really understanding how text escaping works and how you need to do the right kind of encoding as and when output in a particular format is required. This misunderstanding is a widespread cause of broken apps and it is heartbreaking to see it in a ‘security’ book. And then there are the totally bizarre recommendations like adding an ‘admin lock’ column to all your tables to try to enforce access logic. Whut? Oh, and the code's a mess of mixed-up logic and markup, natch.

4 stars at Amazon! Buy your copy now!

Comment: You seem to have an attraction to bad programming books! Speaking of which, do you own a copy of **Hardcore Java**?

Comment: It does sound wonderful! I'll have to keep an eye out for it.

Comment: Yikes. I'll have to find a copy of this just out of morbid curiosity.

Answer (score 8):

I've come across lots of bad programming books, but those have always been ones that I just happened to come accross (e.g. in a bookstore, at a friend's place etc.). The only really bad book that I have ever bought and tried to follow that turned out to be utter garbage was [Java 2: The Complete Reference](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0072224207) by Herb Schild. The TA actually recommended that book.

[image]

I spent the whole semester wondering why that book was filled with irrelevance (that book isn't sure whether it is a tutorial or a reference IMHO). I know of some people who have liked it and claim they derived some benefit from it, but I just ditched the book near the end of the semester and focused on the class notes. Later on I found better books on Java, and really learnt the language.

Edit:
Someone actually "borrowed" the book from me after some years, and failed to return it. So, I guess a least one person liked it.

Comment: Herb Schild: that explains a lot. He has a long history of poor (to put it nicely) C and C++ books.

Comment: @Richard: I wasn't aware of his reputation back then, or I would have never bought this.

Comment: I've got that one.  I didn't think it was bad, but I didn't think it was especially good either.  I got what I needed out of it.

Comment: Someone once said "If you want to before a java guru, this is the book for you". Some professor once remarked "This is an advanced book. Read it after knowing the basics of Java". The "Complete Reference" tag has a great influence on college goers and professors in India.

Comment: @Nivas: As I said, the book seems to me to be confused about its purpose. It follows a narrative style like a tutorial and covers some pretty simple things, and yet does not cover much of the fundamentals of the language in any depth. It also devotes a whole lot of space on the classes in the library like a reference, yet its coverage is far from exhaustive. It is neither a good tutorial nor a any good as a reference. If you like it, good for you. To each his own. But I really don't see anything that's "advanced" java in that book.

Comment: @MAK I completely agree. I had a copy, and I became no Java guru with this book. What I meant was this book is _considered_ a great one in some universities here. I and thats bad news because thats where people start learning these stuff, and whatever book the professor suggests is considered good. I myself don't like this book.

Comment: @Nivas: Oh I see. I live in Bangladesh, so I guess this is a favourite of the many not-so-good professors we have in the subcontinent. The book was put in the course reading list and strongly recommended by the TA (who actually knew little Java, and was probably parroting what the professor said) in my university.

Comment: Anything by Schildt is on my avoid list, and not just because Peter Seebach ripped him to shreds on his first book on C. +1 for this.

Comment: Probably the worst programming book author ever

Comment: I don't know, the library reference is not so useful, but the part which described the language didn't seem bad to me. Of course, at the time I read this book I couldn't really estimate it, but I don't remember having to unlearn anything later. I read it in Russian, though, maybe translators fixed something. I just don't know exactly what it is critisized for, the answer is not very specific.

Answer (score 8):

1. Anything and everything written by Herbert Schildt. Calling this one book is probably a bit of a stretch -- it's more like an eternal case of food poisoning committed to paper.
2. Fractal Programming in C, by Roger T. Stevens. As Leonard Plinth-Garnell would have said, "Exquisitely awful!"
3. Numeric Recipes in [C | C++]. Lots of "recipes", but 1) the code is really Fortran with C-family syntax, and 2) *many* (most?) of the algorithms is propounds are numerically unstable and generally best avoided.

Comment: Sadly, the style of Numerical Recipes is quite popular with many non-programmers, at least with my (physics) professors.

Answer (score 7):

Please forgive me... I was in college and was fascinated with Y2K.  The book proved to be boring and like the hype, was all sensationalism.  Complete garbage.

[image: Time Bomb 2000]

Comment: Y2K was the most sensationalism which I ever see on programming. It was a real, but not that much.

Comment: Yes but there was a method to the madness, IT shops found it a great way to get new equipment and people to fix some long-standing issues nobody wanted to pay for fixing before. Ther was lot of work charged to Y2K that had nothing to do with it but did have to do with the fact that it was easy to get money if you cried, Y2K.

Comment: I've already got my copy of "Time Bomb 2038" reserved. I just have to bank on UPS or whoever delivers it will have already switched to 64-bit systems by then.

Comment: +1 for asking for forgiveness. However I think we both know you won't ever be forgiven for buying this.

Comment: The interesting thing is that Ed Yourdon is an otherwise reasonable, well-respected author, or so I understand. He just made a colossal blunder with his estimation of the impact here.

Comment: Haha - the title!

Answer (score 6):

[image][image]

If you find this crap in a tester's cubicle--immediately fire him/her. This book is for imbeciles written by an imbecile.

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: Everything. It teaches nothing, 0. The whole "book" is just a dumb list of outdated software and (very) naive paraphrasing of software QA terms. If a person finds something interesting in this "book" then such person cannot be in software development/testing.

Comment: What if I find it nailed to the wall of the tester's cubicle with a dagger?...

Answer (score 6):

Oh, and, well, controversially, this, I guess:

[image: Stroustrup 3rd ed]

Stroustrup's [The C++ Programming Language, third edition](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/3rd.html). It's not the worst programming book I've ever read by a long chalk, but it's certainly the most disappointing.

I remember liking the second edition, which was, at least, an attempt at writing in the same terse style as K&R's C masterpiece. Sadly, that edition predates templates and other features of the modern language, so isn't much use today.

The third edition jettisons any attempt at that terseness, ending up with a book three times as long as its predecessor, filling up its pages with endless tedious discussions of the author's ideas of best practices for object-oriented coding and software development in general.

Somewhere in between all the rambling there's a description of how the C++ language works, but good luck finding it. It's a sprawling mess of a book.

(Much like the language, eh?) (Sorry, that was uncalled for.) (Well maybe a *bit* called for.)

Comment: I own a Swedish translation of this book (but I don't think it's of the third edition). Now I don't know if Bjarne wrote in such a manner, but the translation is horrendous: I find it absolutely impossible to read. You're looking in a dictionary half of the time and trying to figure out what exactly is meant by a particular sentence. I must look in an English edition when I get the chance...

Comment: Oh dear! The English version's not so bad, prose-wise. The flights into Bjarne's Philosophy Of Software Engineering are a tiresome read though, and probably not much fun to translate.

Comment: Glad I never "upgraded" then!  Second edition is still the most current one sitting on my shelf at home.  :-)

Comment: I actually read it cover-to-cover in school and thought it was a decent read. Am I the only one who likes this book?

Comment: I had to read it three times before I grasped the concepts it was trying to explain. Only programming book I ever read that didn't stick after the second read.

Comment: His attempt to explain virtual base classes makes no sense at all. But maybe that's because virtual base classes make no sense at all.

Answer (score 6):

It has to be "**Wicked Cool PHP**"

I bought it because it had a robot with a hammer on the front cover,what could go wrong? I thought.  Turns out everything. Pointless examples, terrible code and incorrect security information throughout.

[image]

Comment: I bet you never buy another book with a robot and hammer on the cover!

Comment: You would think that Kirk...

Comment: robot look nice :[+_+]:

Answer (score 5):

**Applying Domain-Driven Design and Patterns: With Examples in C# and .NET**

[image: Applying Domain-Driven Design and Patterns: With Examples in C# and .NET]

The shame was that I love DDD, love the ideas presented in the book and the author is intelligent and knowledgeable; but I've tried reading this book through maybe 5-10 times now and just can't do it. The author needs to know when to stop talk, stop going on tangents, stop providing 'did you know' or 'story about this paragraph' sections on damn near every single page and stop trying to name drop on every paragraph.

Bottom line: The book's got some good information/ideas, except that they're buried in so much BS, that you'll never get to them. This book could have been 1/4 its content, and it would have been good.

Comment: Funny, I really liked that book.  I thought the tangents were helpful.

Comment: I agree with SnOrfus.  This one seems like it should be great, but it reads like a stream-of-consciousness rant.  Sometimes I'm in the mood for it, but in general I prefer a little more structure in a book.

Comment: I used to really like this book, until I understood that in DDD having a "IsValid" or similar method/property on an aggregate root is a bit of an anti-pattern in DDD.

Answer (score 5):

Head First C#. Shame to the Head First family IMO.

[image]

Comment: can you elaborate why you think this?

Comment: I have always thought that head first books are quite good, they target beginners and almost always deliver. But I haven't read this one.

Answer (score 4):

[UML in a NutShell](http://www.amazon.co.uk/UML-Nutshell-Sinan-Alhir/dp/B00007FYAU/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1285326956&sr=8-5) (1st edition).

[image: UML In a NutShell]

Essentially unreadable, needed reviewers to tell the author to start again with some explanation, not just a summary of the standards.

The 2nd edition, on the other hand, is readable and useful.

Comment: But the cat is cute!

Comment: I was going to add this, but I see you beat me to it.

Comment: @Lorenzo: The topic of cats' attempt to take over society by appearing cute is off topic.

Comment: I own 'Algorithms In a Nutshell'. The O'Reilly Errata section has over 50 entries last time I checked. The samples are horrible and most of them are wrong. The book fails to cover a few basic algorithms let a long complete them. 'In a Nutshell' is a horrible series.

Comment: Nutshell is wildly variable. SQL in a Nutshell isn't bad... far from complete or definitive, but did a good job of covering the major syntax differences in the DBMSs it covered.

Comment: UML is horrible. How would one write a *good* book on it? :)

Answer (score 4):

[How to do everything with PHP and MySQL](http://everythingphpmysql.com) by Vikram Vaswani. That book set me back so much when learning programming at first. Horrible code, constant mixing and matching of code and markup, complete ignorance of OOP the barest nod to security throughout and just plain ignoring PHP5, which even then, wasn't exactly brand new.

I wrote a [blog post on programming books](http://blog.webicity.info/2010/08/21/programming-books/) in which I had this picture comparing the two first PHP books I got.

[Compare the size http://blog.webicity.info/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/books-small.jpg](http://blog.webicity.info/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/books-small.jpg)

Guess which has the more accurate title?

Answer (score 3):

I don't remember the title, but I recently saw a high school text book for Visual Basic. The first two chapters were not about coding or even VB related (A history of BASIC would have been an improvement.).

The school could have saved a lot of money by just Googling 'VB Hello World'.

Answer (score 2):

Programming in C++ by Dewhurst and Stark:

[image: Programming in C++]

It may not have been the worst ever.  It makes my list because the first edition cover looked exactly like K&R's *The C Programming Language*, so I was expecting a work of similar quality.  I got a copy 20 years ago, just as C++ was starting to get widespread notice.  This book taught the syntax, but it did nothing to show a C programmer how to take advantage of C++'s features.  I found it a very frustrating book.

Comment: Ah yes, the classic bait-and-switch judge-by-the-cover ruse!

Answer (score 2):

[Pragmatic Version Control using Subversion](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/svn/pragmatic-version-control-using-subversion) - Easily in the bottom rung among all the Pragmatic Programmer books I've read till now. Extremely thin on content. Some might argue that this book is for absolute beginners who are starting out with version control, but that's rubbish - whatever the book has, is not actually worth writing a book for.

Comment: Agreed.  The free online Subversion book (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) is much better.  Also, the index in Pragmatic Version Control using Subversion is useless for finding what you want.

Comment: I got this book in the pragmatic starter kit when I knew zilch about subversion (and really version control in general). It helped my a lot. Woulda been loads better if they used tortoise though. As if anyone uses the commandline for subversion anymore.

Comment: @Snorfus - good that it helped you. I just found it too simplistic. CLI for SVN - some Linux users do :)

Comment: @SnOrfus: I use command line svn all the time -- both on the linux servers, and locally on my Mac.  I have a svn GUI (Versions) which is great for browsing, looking at logs, blame, etc, but I find it faster to pick out specific subsets of files to commit, or look at logs for specific date ranges, via the command line.

Comment: @snorfus If I used svn (which I don't because I hate it), I would use command line. Not everyone uses Windows, you know.

Comment: @mathepic: Considering you hate svn, don't use it, the commandline is the same on windows as any other os IIRC and there are svn guis for every major OS, did you decide to comment purely just to point out that you don't use Windows?

Comment: @snorfus I decided to comment to say that not everyone can use Tortoise, what would be the point of having it in a book about version control? It just doesn't belong there.

Comment: @mathepic: Fair enough. Point taken.

Comment: I loved this book. I am so surprised to see it in this list.

Comment: @JW01 - Can you elaborate on what you loved in this book?

Comment: It was the first book that gave me a 'bigger picture' on how software is organised in a project as 'a file structure'. Was the first book that explained trunks, branches, release candidates, tags etc. Most other books that i have read talk about code at the conceptual level. In fact, I can't think of another book that offers insight into a project's file structure.

Comment: I'm surprised the Pragmatic folks aren't just advising everyone to switch to Git.

Answer (score 1):

I can't remember the name - later I might see if I can dig it out - but there was an ASP.NET book I had that had all the code snippets (and there were a lot) as Visual Studio screenshots.  It seemed cool at first because it showed me exactly where to go in the IDE (I was just learning at that point).  After a while though (Chapter 2, I think), I found I knew where everything was and I was just finding the shots too difficult to read.

Pro C# by Andrew Troelsen was mostly very good, but someone needs to teach the man to use examples properly.  He'd teach one technique for a topic (let's say multithreading), then teach another and compare the two.  The problem is that rather than simply updating the first sample with the new code, he'd write a totally new application that does something totally different, and throw a bunch of extra concepts into the mix as well.

Answer (score 1):

**A Computer Science Tapestry: Exploring Computer Science in C++**

This was assigned reading when I was in college.  Apart from being totally soporific, this book presents things in such a convoluted way, I doubt I could have parsed it without prior programming knowledge: most of my class, in which there was only one experienced coder beside myself, was completely lost.

I gave up after reading only a fraction of the book and tried using it to hold up the end of a wobbly bookcase.  It wasn't great at that, either: a little too thick and the cover was slippery.

Answer (score 1):

[image: book cover]

[Verification of Sequential and Concurrent Programs, Second Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387948961), by Krzysztof R. Apt and Ernst-Rüdiger Olderog.

Maybe it was the subject matter, but I distinctly remember this as being the driest book I have ever read. Getting all the way to the end was a genuine soporific challenge.

Answer (score 0):

[Programming Microsoft Visual C++, 5ed (Kruglinski, Shepherd, Wingo)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1572318570)

Not that the book was bad, but its title is very misleading, especially to people new to C++. The preface of the book promises to teach you how to program in VC++, and a background in C but not C++ is all you need. Truth be told, you absolutely cannot learn anything about C++ from this book.

I owned this book for about 10 years, and recently (after working for a C++/Windows job for 4 years) I started to find *a few* chapters to be a bit useful when explaining stuff to new hires.

People wishing to learn Windows Programming are advised to: (in chronological order)

- Learn C (and preferably get a CS degree)
- Find a C/C++ project team and join it, and focus on the pure C/C++ part of programming to master it
- When something is needed, learn straight from MSDN (it has improved a lot in the last 4 years). Ask your coworkers for code snippets.
- Finally, read this book. It will start to make sense.

Comment: Well, I can't see why you would expect to find much about C++ in a book with that title – in fact, _I_ would have been _annoyed_ if I'd bought it and then found out much of it is wasted on subjects I already know from books that are actually about C++. — But, of course, the authors shouldn't have made that claim in the preface then.

Answer (score -2):

We had a course at the university about knowledge systems. The book was real bad, it wasn't finished and hard to read. The teacher did not follow the book (although it was required for the course) and the exam consisted of multiple choise questions not related to both the book and the course. But fortunately the teacher reused questions of previous exams so the students learned them.

Comment: This sounds like "bad prof" not (just) "bad book"

Comment: "The teacher did not follow the book (although it was required for the course)" I could have said that for 75% of the courses I took in university.

Answer (score -2):

I have yet to come across a book that I haven't found useful.

I don't know why that is, but it is the way it is, isn't it?

Comment: Perhaps you haven't used any terrible books, or perhaps you are too generous: A book can be useful but still cost ten times the time and effort to glean the same value of another book.

Answer (score -3):

There are far too many to list.

All of the SAMS books qualify.

I generally don't care to remember the dumb books.  I sometimes just rip them down the spine (if they are paperback) and throw them out or burn them.  I have not bought too many books recently.

Comment: You could still name one or two.

Comment: You *burn* books?!!